# Rails - Group By Hour - Take Average of Single Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What i'm looking to do is take a single value, group it by the hour and in each hour get an average of that hour into an array like so.

['hour1average','hour2average']

What I have at the moment is below (the > 1 day is important in this specific scenario but would be good to know how to achieve this in general).

code snippit

```
@item.tickers.where("created_at > :day_ago",{day_ago: 1.day.ago}).pluck(:bazaar)
```

In context

```
<%= content_tag :div, id: "last24", class: "last24",  data: {item: @item.name.to_s, prices: @item.tickers.where("created_at > :day_ago",{day_ago: 1.day.ago}).pluck(:bazaar), when: @item.tickers.where("created_at > :day_ago",{day_ago: 1.day.ago}).pluck(:created_at)} do %>
<% end %>
```

I'd also be interested to see how you could get the min/max values for each grouped hour if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hour_group = @item.tickers.where("created_at > :day_ago",{day_ago: 1.day.ago}).group_by {|ticker| ticker.created_at.hour}
```

This will give you a hash as such

```
 { 
   1 => ['Array of items with hour=1'],
   2 => ['Array of items with hour=2']
 }
```

What field do you want the average of? Or do you want to just count the items in each hour group?

To return an array of number of items in each hour

```
group_average_array = [0]*24
hour_group.each_pair do |idx, arr|
  group_average_array[idx] = (arr.map(&:bazaar).sum)/arr.size
end
```

group_average_array will contain the average of bazaar found in each hour.

Comment: Rather than array with the items of hour of 1 for example, I'm looking for a single array that contains the average of each hour group of the field "bazaar"

Comment: ['hour1average','hour2average'] for example

Comment: I get: undefined method `average' for [835835, 835835]:Array

Comment: <% hour_group = @item.tickers.where("created_at > :day_ago",{day_ago: 1.day.ago}).group_by {|ticker| ticker.created_at.hour} %>
42:   <% group_average_array = [0]*24 %>
43:   <% hour_group.each_pair do |idx, arr| %>
44:     <% group_average_array[idx] = arr.map(&:bazaar).average %>
45:   <% end %>
46:   <% debugger %>
47:   <%= content_tag :div, id: "last24", class: "last24",  data: {item: @item.name.to_s, prices: @item.tickers.where("created_at > :day_ago",{day_ago: 1.day.ago}).pluck(:bazaar), when: @item.tickers.where("created_at > :day_ago",{day_ago: 1.day.ago}).pluck(:created_at)} do %>

Comment: updated the answer.... I have this method written for myself and have grown so used to it that I forget its not a builtin

Comment: Hmm running this in a console, the group average array shows something liek this [0,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,221,0,0,0,0,0,]. None of the bazaar entired are 0 so i dont know where this is coming from...

Comment: 0 is because nothing was found in that hour. So instead of doing an if else approach, I went ahead with a generalized one